# Section always grows when resizeing - except when in debug mode stepping through the code

Tags: javascript, dynamic, resize, width

I've got an odd issue, that I can't wrap my mind around.

I have a section in a HTML doc, that I'm resizing by dragging the borders.

When I drag the left or bottom border, all is fine, and the section is resized correctly.

When I drag the top or left border, the box always grow in size.
Except that is, when I'm debugging the code, stepping though it line for line. In that case the box grows or shrinks correctly with the mouse movement.

I'm guessing there is something in the event model, or the style adjustments I don't fully understand.

This is prototype code only, and I'm not using any libraries (just plain vanilla JavaScript).

```
// reSizeData is populated by mouse event that start the drag process. It contain the HTMLElement that are resized (node), and which border is being dragged (action)
var reSizeData = {node: null, action: "", inProgress: false}

function reSize(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    var node = reSizeData.node;
    if (node === undefined) return false;
    var borderWidth = styleCoordToInt(getComputedStyle(node).getPropertyValue('border-left-width'));
    // check and set the flag in reSizeData indicating that a resize is in progress.
    // this makes repeated calls to be dropped until current resize event is complete.
    if (reSizeData.inProgress === false) {
        reSizeData.inProgress = true;   
        if (node.getBoundingClientRect) {
            var rect = node.getBoundingClientRect();
            switch (reSizeData.action) {
                case "left" :
                    // this is only working while debugging
                    node.style.width = Math.max(rect.right - ev.clientX, 20) + 'px';
                    node.style.left = ev.clientX + 'px';
                    break;
                case "right" :
                    // this working perfectly
                    node.style.width = Math.max(ev.clientX - rect.left - borderWidth, 20) + 'px';
                    break;
                case "top":
                    // this is only working while debugging
                    node.style.height = Math.max(rect.bottom - ev.clientY, 20) + 'px';
                    node.style.top = ev.clientY + 'px';
                    break;
                case "bottom":
                    // this is working perfectly
                    node.style.height = Math.max(ev.clientY - rect.top - borderWidth, 20) + 'px';
                    break;
            }
            // clear the resize in progress flag
            reSizeData.inProgress = false;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I found, is that I failed to translate the mouse coordinates the style coordinates, which are affected by the document structure.
What I still haven't resolved is why the code worked when stepping through the code line for line in Firefox debugger.